# Should I put semicolons after JSX expression?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

If I have the following:

```
...
let p1 = <p>qwer</p>
let p2 = <p>asdf</p>
...
```

Should I put semicolons at the end of each of these?

Comment: As long as it doesn't result in unintended behavior, keeping in mind the rules of ASI, it's up to you - you can use them or not

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong to leave it like that, you can put semicolons if you want, but it is better you be consistent and follow one code style check https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode
it will make your life easier